# Team Foundation Move File Deletes Labels but Keeps Changeset History

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, tfs

I have moved some source files from within the TFS GUI from:

```
$Product\AppName1\File
```

to:

```
$Product\AppName Common\File
```

The history of the changeset has been preserved but not the labels - can anyone help?

The strange (and annoying) part of this is that the label history is show after the move but when I commit the move (which is actually a rename in TFS terms) then the label info is gone

Comment: What labels did you want preserved?

Comment: @john - We label all our source after each build so we can easily check out the code for a particular build if we have an issue later on. With this gone it is difficult to work out which version belongs to which build.

Comment: You used the "Move" command in Source Control Explorer? It creates a new changeset. Surely the label still contains the original versions, before the move?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the original label still contains the original versions? If so, then I'll add my comment as an answer (a bit later).

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used the "Move" command in Source Control Explorer? It creates a new changeset. Surely the label still contains the original versions, before the move?

Comment: Yes it does - It was my misunderstanding of how the labelling works! I am using TFS2010 btw. Thanks for the help